# index number for the line time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I am using the below code in the google tag manager custom JavaScript variable, but it returns same index value for every line item, what can be the issue?
Web page link: https://www.amity.edu/programe-list.aspx?fd=all

```
function() {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-container');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
     (function(index){
       elements[i].children[0].children[0].addEventListener("click", myScript);
       function myScript(){
         return("Clicked : ",index);
       }
     })(i);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the 5th line.

It should be `elements[index].children...` in that case.

The updated code:

```
function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-container');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    (function(index){
      elements[index].children[0].children[0].addEventListener("click", myScript);
      function myScript(){
        return("Clicked : ",index);
      }
    })(i);
  } 
}
```

Comment: now it is giving "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way from Simo's blog

[Blog link](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/get-position-index-of-visible-element/)

Although the post is say about visibility element. I test it with click on my website.

This might work

```js
function() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-container a'),
      el   = {{Click Element}};
  return [].indexOf.call(list, el) + 1;
}
```

If it is not working, you might need to provide the screenshot about the click element from your GTM preview.

Comment: It is giving the incorrect index number. Link for the screenshot: https://imgur.com/bQakxNM

Comment: Can you describe more about the incorrect index? Here is the index from your html. https://imgur.com/KSeOnw8. The order can not be changed if you want to count the index from up to bottom first. Because the raw html rendered it left and right